# make user attend event through sdk

Tags: facebook-fql

I was wondering if it's possible to make a user attend an event through the sdk (probably fql).

I've been looking at the wiki for FQL info as well as the graph api. But both look like they only support fetching info and not changing...

Any suggestions? I would like to build this feature into an application....

Comment: First thing that's coming to mind is kidnap. :)

Comment: hehe... well I think I've found a solution.. the REST apis seems to do the trick..

Comment: Jakob, can you please post your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the new graph API my solution looks like this:

```
Facebook* facebook = [Facebook new];
[facebook authorize:_facebookApiKey permissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"rsvp_event",@"user_events", nil] delegate:self];

NSString *eventIDWithSlashPrefix = @"/eventID";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[params setObject:_facebook.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:[eventIDWithSlashPrefix stringByAppendingString:@"/attending"] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```